# Angular Component content does not show after upgrading to angular 6.0

Tags: angular, upgrade

I upgraded my Angular 5.2 project to Angular 6, including upgrading rxjs and installing rxjs-compat.

I have a landing page that sets the input variable *isLoggedIn* for a top bar component included in the template.  The issue is that the top bar content does not appear at all in this page since the upgrade.

Looking at the elements on Chrome dev tools, I can see the landing component, and a line for the top bar component, but no content as I would expect.

However, if I put the top bar component directly into the App component, it shows up as expected (but I don't want it there).  The app component, of course, has a router outlet for the landing page, which should then contain the top bar component.

Ngrx is working fine, setting the state, and the selectors are working fine.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Here is the relevant code:

Landing Component html:

```
<wvr-top-bar [isLoggedIn]="loggedIn$ | async"></wvr-top-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Landing Component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {CognitoService} from '../../services/cognito.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {select, Store} from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromUser from '../../reducers';

@Component({
  selector: 'wvr-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.css']
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

  loggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public cognito: CognitoService,
    private store: Store<fromUser.State>) {

    this.loggedIn$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromUser.getLoggedIn));
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn$
      .subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {

        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

top bar html

```
<div class="center-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../../../../assets/wvr-b.svg" alt=""></a>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-expand-md bg-color2">

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <!--<span class="navbar-toggler-icon text-light"></span>-->
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Studio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Resources
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Future Feature</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="secondary-nav float-right">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" (click)="logout()"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" (click)="login()"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" routerLink='profile'>Profile</li>

    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

top bar component ts:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {CognitoService} from '../../../user/services/cognito.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'wvr-top-bar',
  templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.css']
})
export class TopBarComponent {

  @Input() isLoggedIn;

  constructor(public cognito: CognitoService, private router: Router) { }

  logout() {
    this.cognito.signOut();
  }

  login() {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

}
```

App Component ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CognitoService} from '../../../user/services/cognito.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromUser from '../../../user/reducers';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'wvr-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  loggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(public cognito: CognitoService, private router: Router, private store: Store<fromUser.State>) {
    this.cognito.getCurrentUser();
    this.loggedIn$ = this.store.select(fromUser.getLoggedIn);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn$.subscribe((isLoggedIn) => {
      isLoggedIn ? this.router.navigate(['landing']) : this.router.navigate(['login']);
    });
  }
}
```

element inspection from devtools:

[image: html rendered]

augury

[image]

Comment: One thing that looks a bit off is that you subscribe to loggedIn$ in both AppComponent and LandingComponent and navigate. Not sure if that is the cause of your problem, but it looks like a source for bugs ;)

Comment: not a source for bugs since the state is all in one place and the subscriptions will automatically update the data appropriately. That's the beauty of ngrx store.  Since both app and landing are containers, it is appropriate that they both manage the store for their subcomponents.

Comment: I think it is. It is not about managing the state, but what you do after state changes, in this case I mean specifically the ```router.navigate``` part in your subscriptions. Let's say you suddenly change how you want to treat logged in and change the behavior in your app component, you might forget that you do the same thing in your landing component. I think things like that should best be handled in one place and not all over your application.

Comment: ok, I see your point  Much appreciated.